# Oracle insert if not exists statement

Tags: oracle

```
insert into OPT (email, campaign_id) values('mom@cox.net',100)
where not exists( select * from OPT where (email ="mom@cox.net" and campaign_id =100)) ;
```

> Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

how to insert a new row if it doesn't exists in Oracle?

Answer (score 118):

```
insert into OPT (email, campaign_id) 
select 'mom@cox.net',100
from dual
where not exists(select * 
                 from OPT 
                 where (email ='mom@cox.net' and campaign_id =100));
```

Answer (score 28):

The correct way to insert something (in Oracle) based on another record already existing is by using the [MERGE](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=203) statement.

Please note that this question has already been answered here on SO:

- [oracle insert if row not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147874/oracle-insert-if-row-not-exists)
- [insert if not exists oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702832/insert-if-not-exists-oracle)

Answer (score 12):

```
MERGE INTO OPT
USING
    (SELECT 1 "one" FROM dual) 
ON
    (OPT.email= 'mom@cox.net' and OPT.campaign_id= 100) 
WHEN NOT matched THEN
INSERT (email, campaign_id)
VALUES ('mom@cox.net',100) 
;
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
insert into OPT       (email,        campaign_id) 
select 'mom@coxnet' as email, 100 as campaign_id from dual MINUS
select                 email,        campaign_id from OPT;
```

If there is already a record with `mom@cox.net`/`100` in OPT, the `MINUS` will subtract this record from the `select 'mom@coxnet' as email, 100 as campaign_id from dual` record and nothing will be inserted. On the other hand, if there is no such record, the `MINUS` does not subract anything and the values `mom@coxnet`/`100` will be inserted.

As *p.marino* has already pointed out, `merge` is probably the better (and more correct) solution for your problem as it is specifically designed to solve your task.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to leverage the `INSERT ALL` syntax from oracle,

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO table1(email, campaign_id) VALUES (email, campaign_id)
WITH source_data AS
 (SELECT 'mom@cox.net' email,100 campaign_id
  FROM   dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dad@cox.com' email,200 campaign_id
  FROM   dual)      
SELECT email
      ,campaign_id
FROM   source_data src
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM   table1 dest
        WHERE  src.email = dest.email
        AND    src.campaign_id = dest.campaign_id);
```

`INSERT ALL` *also allow us to perform a conditional insert into multiple tables based on a sub query as source*.

There are some really clean and nice examples are there to refer.

1. [oracletutorial.com](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-insert-all/#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20multitable%20insert%20statement,tables%20based%20on%20specified%20conditions.&text=If%20you%20specify%20the%20ALL,executes%20the%20corresponding%20INTO%20clause.)
2. [oracle-base.com/](https://oracle-base.com/)