# How to insert conditionally in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've read [here](http://psoug.org/snippet/INSERT-WHEN_588.htm) that the syntax looks like this:

```
INSERT
WHEN ([Condition]) THEN
INTO [TableName] ([ColumnName])
VALUES ([VALUES])
ELSE
INTO [TableName] ([ColumnName])
VALUES ([VALUES])
SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [TableName];
```

But I don't want to provide values from another table. I just want to type them, so I've got:

```
INSERT 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'JOE') 
THEN
INTO BAR (NAME, AGE) 
VALUES ('JOE', 50)
```

and this produces exception: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword.

I want to perform an insert if given value is found in another table.

Comment: I think you can only use that inside a PL/SQL procedure, not in plain SQL. The `WHEN` clause is not part of the SQL INSERT clause: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using with `select` works. Your query wasn't working because there is a problem with `values` keyword when inserting conditionally.

```
INSERT 
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'JOE') 
THEN
INTO BAR (NAME, AGE) 
SELECT 'JOE', 50 FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 5):

So, I've found an indirect way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639922/1873995) and solution for my question would be:

```
INSERT INTO BAR (NAME, AGE) 
SELECT 'JOE', 50
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOO WHERE NAME = 'JOE')
```

but it doesn't explain why I have to use `SELECT` statement in `INSERT WHEN`

Comment: I assume it is because this system relies on the `INSERT` aborting when the `SELECT` it relies on returns no results.